# VueJS Dynamic Bar Chart Colors

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Given a bar graph with 2 data sets. How can I give each bar its own color?

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .style("fill", function(d,i) { console.log(i.fill) }  // <- first red, second blue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm too lazy to set up a demo for what I think might work, but I imagine you want an array of colors like:

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue'];
```

then in your callback for `fill` you can do like this:

```
return colors[i % colors.length];
```

If I'm correct in assuming `i` is an index for the `bar` you're on.